# .NET Language for cleanest implementation of ISO 8583 parser

Tags: parsing, iso8583

What would be the best .NET language for a new ISO 8583 parser, if we're talking about dev time and comprehensibility (not so much about performance)?
I'm currently mostly involved with C#, but have also worked with VB.Net, and have introductory level knowledge of functional programming (so F# is not completely out of the question).
If domain of problem is parsing finite depth textual data structures with bitmaps of fields, I'm asking which language is the best fit? (if your suggestion is Javascript or Perl I'll take a note of that too).

Comment: There isn't any "best".  YOu have to build a "parser" to read binary formatted messages.  This is mostly a giant state machine based on what I've seen from the IOS 8583 spec but I didn't look at it very hard.  You can implement state machines in pretty much any langauge easily.

Comment: It depends on the application you are building. Are you building the client or server?

Comment: I'm looking at both

Comment: @steakoverflow Do a search on nuget.org. There are several packages there.